# Gabriel's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

Need some help with Gabriel's theorem, doing the part "if a graph is of finite type, it must be a Dynkin graph" like this:

Let $\vec{Q}$ be of finite type. All representations is a direct sum of indecomposables representations.

Let $v\in \mathbb{Z}_+\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_+=\mathbb{Z}_+^I$ where $I$ is the number of vertices of the quiver.

Exists a finite number of isomorphism classes os representations with dimension $v$. If $V_1,\cdots, V_s$ are the indecomposables representations, we have
$$V_1^{d_1}\oplus \cdots \oplus V_s^{d_s}.$$

We have only a finite number of choices $d_1,\cdots , d_s$ to have a representation with dimension $v$.

Then I have this property: two elements $x, x' \in R(v)$ define isomorphic representations of $\vec{Q}$ iff they are in the same $GL(v)$ orbit.

That give me this: the action of $GL(v)$ on $R(\vec{Q}, v)$ has only a finite number of orbits.

Then I have that exists a orbit $O_x$ with dim$O_x=$dim$R(v)$, so
$$\text{dim}GL(v)-\text{dim}O_x=\text{dim}G_x$$
then
$$\sum_{i\in I}v_i^2-\text{dim}R(v)=\text{dim}G_x$$
and
$$G_x=\{ g\in GL(v);g(x)=x \}.$$

Now we have that,
$$\sum_{i\in I}v_i^2-\sum_h v_{s(h)} v_{t(h)}\geq 1$$
$$\sum_{i\in I}v_i^2-\sum_h v_{s(h)} v_{t(h)}=<v,v>=q(v)\geq 1$$
then $q$ is positive defined, so $\vec{Q}$ is dinkyn.

This all is true for $v\in \mathbb{Z}_+\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_+=\mathbb{Z}_+^I$, how do I show that it's true for $v\in \mathbb{Z}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}^I$?

Comment: Write an arbitrary $v$ as $v=v_+-v_-$, where $v_+,v_-$ are both in $\mathbb Z_+^I$ and have disjoint supports, so for each $i\in I$ at least one of them has a zero in position $i$. Then $(v_+,v_i)\geq0$, where $(-,-)$ is the symmetric bilinear form obtained from $\langle-,-\rangle$. Now compute $(v,v)=2q(v)$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. But I don't understand the final part, I did this: $$q(v)=<v,v>=q(v_+)-2<v_+,v_->+q(v_-)\geq 2-2<v_+,v_->$$ how do I use the $(v_+,v_i)\geq 0$ in this?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. We have $(v_+,v_-)\leq0$. Also, I was using the symmetric bilinear form $(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle$.

Comment: But why is $(v_+,v_-)\leq 0$?

Comment: $(x,y)=2\sum_ix_iy_i-\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x_iy_j$, where $a_{ij}$ is the number of edges joining $i$ and $j$. So, if $x$ and $y$ have disjoint supports, then the first sum is zero, and $(x,y)\leq0$.